# Swift 3 casting issue with UnsafeMutableRawPointer - AudioQueue

Tags: swift, casting, swift3, audioqueue

I'm trying to convert to Swift 3 syntax the following code:

```
fileprivate func generateTone(_ buffer: AudioQueueBufferRef) {
        if noteAmplitude == 0 {
            memset(buffer.pointee.mAudioData, 0, Int(buffer.pointee.mAudioDataBytesCapacity))
        } else {
            let count: Int = Int(buffer.pointee.mAudioDataBytesCapacity) / MemoryLayout<Float32>.size
            var x: Double = 0
            var y: Double = 0
            let audioData = UnsafeMutablePointer<Float32>(buffer.pointee.mAudioData)

            for frame in 0..<count {
                x = noteFrame * noteFrequency / kSampleRate
                y = sin (x * 2.0 * M_PI) * noteAmplitude
                audioData[frame] = Float32(y)

                noteAmplitude -= noteDecay
                if noteAmplitude < 0.0 {
                    noteAmplitude = 0
                }

                noteFrame += 1
            }
        }

        buffer.pointee.mAudioDataByteSize = buffer.pointee.mAudioDataBytesCapacity
    }
```

I'm stuck with:

```
let audioData = UnsafeMutablePointer<Float32>(buffer.pointee.mAudioData)
```

Xcode complains:

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UnsafeMutablePointer'
>   with an argument list of type '(UnsafeMutableRawPointer)'

[image]

The project is available at [here](https://github.com/zerdzhong/SwiftAudioQueueDemo/tree/fa0d584a2b5c490597c372c00ff2011d8adc6a9f)

**Any help would be very appreciated :)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mAudioData` is a "untyped pointer"(`UnsafeMutableRawPointer`), and you
can convert it to a typed pointer with `assumingMemoryBound`:

```
let audioData = buffer.pointee.mAudioData.assumingMemoryBound(to: Float32.self)
```

See [SE-0107 UnsafeRawPointer API](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0107-unsaferawpointer.md)
for more information about raw pointers.

Comment: Yes, it's pretty straightforward for me now. Thanks Martin!

Comment: Hello Artur, would you mind updating your sample project with your solution?